# Rooting again after installing LineageOS?

Tags: rooting, lineageos, motorola, supersu, motorola-moto-g3

After following the following steps:

- rooting a motorola g3,
- installing TWRP
- wiping the phone (without micro-sd present) with TWRP
- installing lineageOS
- wiping the phone (without micro-sd present) with TWRP
- Installing SlimOS
- wiping the phone (without micro-sd present) with TWRP
- Installing LineageOS
- Installing Root checker basic
- Finding it does not have proper root acces
- Rebooting to fastboot>recovery>TWRP>Install
- Installing http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=3655401&d=1456122222 (as linked specifically for the Moto G 3 2015 generation here: https://motog5.net/unlock-bootloader-install-twrp-root-moto-g3/)*
- Rebooting,
- checking Root checker basic
- Finding it does not have proper root access
- Noticing this explanation: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=root+lineage&atb=v119-6&iax=videos&ia=videos&iai=L8rwPV5ZhhA
- enabling in debugging mode:
- Root access for ADB and All apps
- checking Root checker basic
- Finding it does not have proper root access
- Reboot in fastmode>TWRP>Install the supersu file
- Reboot check in Root check basic whether root has been obtained, root has not been obtained.
- Root access for ADB and All apps
- checking Root checker basic
- Finding it does not have proper root access
- Reboot in fastmode>TWRP>Install the supersu file
- It does not give a red error bar but it reads:

> Boot image patcher
>
> ---
>
> - Finding boot image
>     --- Boot image:/ /dev/block/mmcblk0p31
> - Extracting ramdisk
> - Decrompressing ramdisk
> - Checking Patch status
> - Creating Backup
> - Patching sepolicy
>     --- Failure, aborting
>
>   ---
>
> Important notice
>
> ---
>
> If TWRP offers to install SuperSU do *NOT* Let it!
>
> ---

I thought perhaps the supersu file needs to be changed since now it is for a LineageOS in stead of for the MOTO G3 2015 edition stock android, so I tried the following 3 files as well:

From:
https://www.lineageosrom.com/2016/12/how-to-enable-root-in-lineage-os-using.html
TO:
https://www.lineageosrom.com/2017/01/download-supersuzp-and-su-removalzip.html
To:
https://download.lineageos.org/extras

1. https://mirrorbits.lineageos.org/su/addonsu-15.1-arm-signed.zip
2. https://mirrorbits.lineageos.org/su/addonsu-15.1-arm64-signed.zip
3. https://mirrorbits.lineageos.org/su/addonsu-15.1-x86-signed.zip

Only the 3d did not give a red error.

So as much of a trivial challenge it may appear to be, I was curious if anyone can point out which mistake I am making in trying to give the device root-access again. Other suggestions are welcome as well!

*Note, this was also the file that allowed me to root it the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already found out, LineageOS has its own, built-in, lightweight SU solution (`addonsu`), which is the only one supported officially (the team does not adore Magisk/SuperSU).

Note that officially LOS only provides [14.1 builds](http://download.lineageos.org/osprey) for your device. Assuming that's the version you're running, using the addonsu for 15.1 you will naturally bump into problems. As indicated in the [source](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_motorola_msm8916-common/blob/cm-14.1/BoardConfigCommon.mk#L34), your device is an `arm` one, so use [addonsu-14.1-arm-signed.zip](https://mirrorbits.lineageos.org/su/addonsu-14.1-arm-signed.zip) instead.

Magisk/SuperSU are reported by other users to work well enough, but you will need newer packages that work with higher Android versions, and the one you initially used (SuperSU 2.62) isn't enough.

Comment: Thank you for your overcomplete answer! And I appreciate the link to the source.  I was curious why the team does not adore Magisk/SuperSu, and I will look into it.

Comment: The team doesn't want errors caused by 3rd-party addons - which would be hard to recreate and track down - to pollute their Reddit and bug-reporting platform.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you had Lineage (im on 14.1 right now & i love this rom), but you wanted, instead, the excitement, unreliability, the Wonder, of 3rd-party root management.
  Yeah, I used to smoke a lotta that, too. JK.  CM/LOS's su is way more stable, predictable, user-friendly, and PRIVATE than most other root-solutions. Seems you weren't aware of the add-on at first, but in the future, Google everything about your device before flashing every file that comes in a zip-format.  Knowing your architecture  is kinda a big deal in the root/modding communities (im curious how the x86 add-on was the least error-throwing on your arm device). You're lucky that root access was the only issue you were fighting.  I can laugh at you because I've been there, done that.  You did right by asking, though.  Live and learn.

Comment: Thank you for your elaboration Rick, it is a good reminder to check the architectures and versions of my hardware and software before I flash anything on it!